# How do I create a hyperlink in java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, hyperlink

I'm going through the [google app engine tutorials](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingusers)

I'm very new to google app engine, java and web programming in general. So my question is, at the bottom of the page it says to add a link to allow the user to log out. So far I've got this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

    if(user != null){
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, " + user.getNickname());

        String logoutLink = String.format("<a href=\"%s\">Click here to log out.</a>",
            userService.createLogoutURL(req.getRequestURI()));
        resp.getWriter().println(logoutLink);
    }else {
        resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
    }
}
```

However instead of a link, the full string is printed to the screen including the tags. When I look at the page source, I have no  tags or any of the other stuff that goes with a webpage. I guess that makes sense considering I've done nothing to output any of that. Do I just do a bunch of resp.GetWriter().println() statements to output the rest of the webpage, or is there something else I don't know about?

Thanks!

Comment: resp.setContentType('text/plain') says that you want plain text, not HTML (with links and other tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the content type to `text/html` instead of `text/plain`.The `<a href` link is a html elemt.Then only the browser will rebder this as a link.

Comment: Quick follow on question.. In order to have a full webpage with <html> <body> etc, do I need to output this all by hand or is there some webpage object I can fill out and call a write() method or something?

Comment: @Justin984, you do not have to create the html by hand in the code like this.There are lot of frameworks that will do the job for you.For example, wicket and freemarker frameworks can be used to render the html O/P for you.

Comment: Cool, that sounds much easier. Thanks again!